# CSS selector not working with absolute positioned divs

Tags: html, css

I have some CSS that works with CodePen, but does not work on my website. I'm trying to select the .appraisals class for background color manipulation for an opaque screen slider that contains information. When I use a selector to change the background as seen on my CodePen, the background color does not change on my live website, more specifically, the process of selecting the div with nth-of-type does not work. Does anyone have any idea?

```css
#hero {
  height: 92.5vh;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.appraisals {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.appraisals:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color:red;
  opacity: .5;
}

.appraisals:nth-of-type(2){
  background-color:blue;
  opacity: .5;
}

.appraisals:nth-of-type(3){
  background-color:green;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero">
  <div class="appraisals">
    <div class="appraisals_wrap">
      <div class="appraisals_text">
        <blockquote>
          <p>HELLO</p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="appraisals">
    <div class="appraisals_wrap">
      <div class="appraisals_text">
        <blockquote>
          <p>HELLO</p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="appraisals">
    <div class="appraisals_wrap">
      <div class="appraisals_text">
        <blockquote>
          <p>HELLO</p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls explain what you need, as they all `position:absolute` so all will overlap to each other, so on browser it will look like you have single `hello` appraisal element. now what you want to do with it?

Comment: The problem is I cannot use a CSS selector to select the elements when I use :nth-of-type selector.

Comment: as I explained above, these 3 are absolute positioned div, so they are coming on top of others, and using your `css-selectors` you have assigned them color `red/blue/green` and because `css-selectors` are working they are setting different color to all these 3, and because `opacity:0.5` its showing you the combination of all these 3 color, for time being just remove the `position:absolute` and see you will get all 3 in sequence and notice all 3 have their own different color you defined in you `css-selector` so your selector is working fine.

Comment: I've answered my own question, it didn't really solve my question but I appreciate you trying.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Anyone having trouble with using selectors for elements, remember to exhaust all selectors such as `:nth-last-of-type` when selecting elements!!! For some reason, `:nth-of-type` did not work, but `:nth-last-of-type` did.